# How to configure Nginx to support PHP-FPM on Mac OS X

Tags: nginx, php, web-server, mac-osx

I am making a website with a contact form, and I want to use PHP. The website is hosted on my simple local server using NGINX. I know NGINX uses FastCGI and PHP-FPM, but being new to this, I'm not sure how to configure everything to make it all work. This is what I have in my nginx.conf file:

```
server {
    listen       7070;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /Users/vibhusharma/Sites/JCA;
        access_log "/Users/vibhusharma/Sites/JCA/jca_access.log";
        error_log  "/Users/vibhusharma/Sites/JCA/jca_errors.log";
        index  index.html index.htm;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;

        #fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$; 
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #fastcgi_index index.php; 
        #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name; 
        #fastcgi_buffers 256 128k; 
        #fastcgi_connect_timeout 300s; fastcgi_send_timeout 300s; 
        #fastcgi_read_timeout 300s; 
        #include fastcgi_params;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000

    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           html;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
```

What else do I need to do to get my server to interpret my php file? Thank you!

Comment: Not sure if it will help, but I am building my web app using angularjs, which is why the `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;` is there

Comment: So...what works? What doesn't? What's the question?

Comment: @gf_ I am getting a "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway)" when i try to load a test php file to my localhost in the browser

Comment: Are you sure that `127.0.0.1:9000` is correct?

Comment: @gf_ I'm not sure about that, but what would I change it to?

Comment: :) Well, you're missing fundamental basics, right? :( Why did you put `127.0.0.1:9000` inside your config? I can't tell you what to put inside...because at least the port could be nearly anything, actually. You could run `netstat -tulpn` (as root / via sudo) to check for the correct data..

Comment: @gf_ I didn't add or change anything! Those lines were in my nginx.conf, including the 127.0.0.1:9000, I just uncommented them.

Comment: Alright...anyway, I guess, this is incorrect, hence you're getting the failure you've provided. You've to fill in the correct data, see my previous comment to get an idea how to find the right data..

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled PHP? Apparently it's not done by default in OS-X. That or maybe it's not installed.

http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/10/install-apache-php-mysql-mac-os-x/